# Exclude a class in Fluent Mappings

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Here is the current code for fluent mappings in my project

```
public FluentConfiguration Setup(Action<MappingConfiguration> mappingConfigurationAction)
    {
        Assembly mappingsAssembly = typeof(SessionFactory).Assembly;

        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(_connection)
                          .AdoNetBatchSize(1000)
                          .ShowSql()
                          .FormatSql()
                          .Dialect<NhibernateDialect>
                          )
            .Mappings(m =>
                          {
                              m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingsAssembly).Conventions.AddAssembly(
                                  mappingsAssembly).ExportTo(@"C:\Mappings");


                              m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingsAssembly);)

                              if (mappingConfigurationAction != null)
                              {
                                  mappingConfigurationAction(m);
                              }
                          }
            );
    }
```

What this does is that it includes all the classes that are in the current assembly/project into the mapping assembly. I have been trying to exclude one particular file/class from the mapping assembly without any luck.

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

see [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration#Automappings):
`AutoMap.AssemblyOf<YourEntity>(type => type.Namespace.EndsWith("Entities"))`

Comment: As you can see in my code, I am using a mix of fluent and HBM mappings due to a requirement in my project. I cannot use automap.

Comment: Link is broken, I am not able to find this overload. Can you please update.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the advice to have a "marker interface":

```
public interface IMappable
{

}


public class MyMappableClass : IMappable 
{
}

public class MyNonMappableClass
{
}
```

To distinguish the classes you want to include in the mapping.

For instance [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653060/fluent-nhibernate-error-the-entity-classmap1-doesnt-have-an-id-mapped) mentions it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my problem:

```
foreach (Type mappingClass in mappingClasses)
                                  {
                                      if (!mappingClass.Namespace.Contains("Adapter.Common") &&
                                          !mappingClass.Namespace.Contains("OracleMapping"))
                                      {
                                          m.FluentMappings.Add(mappingClass);
                                      }
                                  }
```

But I still have the issue with filtering for the HBM mappings which I cannot achieve with the above code.

Comment: missing code: var mappingClasses = mappingsAssembly.GetTypes();