# Fluent NHibernate error: The entity 'ClassMap`1' doesn't have an Id mapped

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm converting a previous project from using normal NHibernate hbm.xml mappings to Fluent NHibernate. Currently, I'm stuck on what should be one of the last steps to getting this working. I've added a derived class for DefaultAutomappingConfiguration to modify my ID naming convention. The string "Id" is appended to the class name:

```
    public override bool IsId(FluentNHibernate.Member member)
    {
        return member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "Id";
    }
```

This should make "Agency" have an ID in a field named "AgencyId". Instead, I'm getting this error:

```
The entity 'ClassMap`1' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).
{Name = "ClassMap`1" FullName = "FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap`1[[BackendDb.Model.Agency, BackendDb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
```

I made a breakpoint on the IsId function to see what's going on:

```
{Property: Cache}
{Name = "ClassMap`1" FullName = "FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap`1[[BackendDb.Model.Agency, BackendDb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
```

What is this? The object is not something I've created. Every other object passes through this function fine, and the ones I actually wanted to map are returning the proper value.

My Session factory looks something like this:

```
var cfg = new MapConfig();
return Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
.ConnectionString(m => m.Server(@".\SqlExpress")
    .Database("{some dbname}")
    .TrustedConnection()))
.Mappings(m =>
    m.AutoMappings
        .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Agency>(cfg))
)
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Annoyingly, it seems that this somehow caused the three tables I was testing Fluent NHibernate on in my dev database to be **emptied**. What the hell?

Comment: Is your 'Agency' class implementing or extending ClassMap?  You shouldn't have any reference to it unless you are using mapping files.

Comment: Yes:     public class AgencyMap : ClassMap<Agency>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sessionfactory is trying to automap all classes in the assembly that contains your `Agency` class based on this directive: `Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Agency>(cfg))`. Since you have an `AgencyMap` in the assembly and`ClassMap<>` does not have an `Id` property, FNH is throwing an error.

If you want to use `ClassMap<>` configurations, instead of (or in addition to) declaring an automapping configuration, declare a fluent mapping:

```
m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Agency>();
```

If you don't need AutoMappings, remove the `.AutoMappings.Add' directive.

However, if you want to use AutoMappings, you need to tell FNH what classes you want to map. To handle this, I usually define a marker interface:

```
public abstract class Entity : IPersistable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IPersistable
{
}
```

Then, in the class that I derive from `DefaultAutomappingConfiguration`, I tell FNH to only map the classes that have that interface (you can limit the mapped classes however you see fit):

```
public class EntityAutoMappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (IPersistable));
    }

}
```

To handle the primary key mapping, I create a convention class:

```
public class PrimaryKeyNamePlusId : IIdConvention 
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name+"Id");
    }
}
```

Finally, I configure my SessionFactory to use the configuration/convention classes:

```
 m.AutoMappings.AssemblyOf<Entity>(new EntityAutoMappingConfiguration())
            .IgnoreBase<Entity>()
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<Entity>()
            .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity>();
```

Comment: Changing the automapping to just m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Agency>(); seems to have worked. I'm going to test this with some additional entities instead of just the one though.

Comment: That should work fine. You don't need to do the automapping if you don't want to. However, using automapping+conventions can save you a lot of time down the road. Check out this post if you're interested: http://iamnotmyself.com/2011/06/22/using-fluent-nhibernate-classmaps-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: I'm working my way up to these things. Using Fluent NHibernate is something I put off doing when first implementing NHibernate (it was hard enough as it was), so I will save that for later. Unless it's really trivial, then I will do it now. I'm using a legacy database, so I don't really feel like setting up all of the conventions right now.

Comment: I totally understand. Good luck with the rest of your conversion effort. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ClassMap` in combination with the automapper unless you also configure the automapper to ignore the Entites for which you are using ClassMap and their respective mapping files.

In my case, I happen to use a custom attribute to indicate classes which *should* be automapped, so I can toss all sorts of garbage I don't want mapped into my .dll without having Fluent try to automap it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add this attribute to entity classes which should be automapped by Fluent.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class AutomapAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

And in my `DefaultAutomappingConfiguration` override class:

```
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return (type.Namespace == "Data.Entities" 
            && type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutomapAttribute), false).Length > 0);
    }
```

Of course, you don't need to check for an attribute if you just keep your automapped entities in a different namespace from other classes.